# How do you use the SPLIT function to separate unseparated characters in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google

I have tried the function SPLIT with the argument "" and it does not work.

I have a list that is phylogenetic code, so in the source file it's structured like: 10??12103??? etc., and I want to insert it into a Google sheet and split it to line up with some precoded materials for other taxa.

Answer (score 1):

SPLIT will work:

```
=SPLIT(A2,"?",0,1)
```

Here, SPLIT views the split character (i.e, "?") as the same whether there is 1, or whether there are 500 of them in a row.

Of course, this can be applied to an entire column as well:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",SPLIT(A2:A,"?",0,1)))
```

Your post shows "?" as the non-numeric characters. However, you may simply have meant that those question marks stand for any of various non-numeric characters. In that case, use this:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"[^0-9]","?"),"?",0,1)
```

...or for the whole column...

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"[^0-9]","?"),"?",0,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Each line of your data file is 12 characters long, and consists of four elements: two digits, twp question marks, five digits and three question marks. The question marks are separators.

`SPLIT` is not a good option in this case because the separators are not consistent. Try `MID` instead.

- `=value(mid(A1,1,2))` - will return the first two characters
- `=value(mid(A1,5,5))` - will return the five character sequence

If you use `MID` alone, it will return a string. I have wrapped the formula in the `VALUE` function in order to return a value. You can ignore this if the string is all you need.